# Optimize slow psql query

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

I have a psql query which is quite slow. It uses from 0.7 up to 5s to execute, which is way too long. I've tried to optimize using *explain analyze* and adding some indexes, but it hasn't helped enough (but without the index the query was exceptionally slow!) The DB is vacuumed on a regular basis, and totally the DB contains about 3 million rows, with several rows per id.

Here is the sql query:

```
WITH min_match AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT ON ("id") *
    FROM cars
    WHERE
      "publicationDate" >= NOW() - interval '250 days' AND
      "mileage" BETWEEN({mileage} - 30000) AND ({mileage} + 30000) AND 
      "model" = '{model}' AND
      "manufacturer" = '{manufacturer}' AND
      "modelYear" = {modelYear} AND
      "driveWheels" = '{driveWheels}' AND
      "fuelType" = '{fuelType}' AND
      "chassisType" = '{chassisType}' AND
      "registrationClass" = '{registrationClass}' AND
      "publisherType" = 'private' AND
      "vehicleTransmission" = '{vehicleTransmission}' AND
      "power" <= ({power} * 1.3) AND
      "power" >= ({power} * 0.7) AND
      "engineVolume" <= 5.0 AND
      "power" <= 500
    ORDER BY "id", "lastUpdateDate" DESC, "eventTime" DESC
),
full_match AS (
    SELECT * FROM min_match
    WHERE
     "engineVolume" = {engineVolume} AND
     "power" = {power} AND
     "numberOfSeats" = {numberOfSeats}
)
SELECT *
FROM
    full_match
        RIGHT JOIN min_match
        ON full_match."id" = min_match."id"
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN (min_match."state" = 'activated') THEN CURRENT_DATE - min_match."publicationDate"
       WHEN (min_match."unPublicationDate" is null) THEN age(CURRENT_DATE) - interval '1 year'
       ELSE CURRENT_DATE - min_match."unPublicationDate"
  END ASC,
  (abs(min_match."power" - {power}) + abs(min_match."engineVolume" - {engineVolume}) + abs(min_match."numberOfSeats" - {numberOfSeats})),
  abs(min_match."mileage" - {mileage}),
  min_match."lastUpdateDate" DESC
LIMIT 30
```

I have tried several indexes, right now I have this one:

```
CREATE INDEX car_list_query_index
ON car_list_view ("publicationDate",
                  "mileage",
                  "model",
                  "manufacturer",
                  "modelYear",
                  "driveWheels",
                  "fuelType",
                  "chassisType",
                  "registrationClass",
                  "publisherType",
                  "power",
                  "engineVolume",
                  "vehicleTransmission",
                  "numberOfSeats");
```

From what I see in *explain analyze* this index is indeed used. It's the *min_match* part which is the slowest, but I'm not really sure how to be able to optimize this more. I've tried with a materialized view which also helped a little bit, but this requires some maintaning so I'd prefer to avoid using it.

Here's the output from explain analyze:

```
 Limit  (cost=417930.63..417930.64 rows=1 width=268) (actual time=706.714..706.714 rows=0 loops=1)
   CTE min_match
     ->  Unique  (cost=417930.46..417930.47 rows=1 width=1235) (actual time=706.684..706.684 rows=0 loops=1)
           ->  Sort  (cost=417930.46..417930.47 rows=1 width=1235) (actual time=706.683..706.683 rows=0 loops=1)
                 Sort Key: cars."id", cars."lastUpdateDate" DESC, cars."eventTime" DESC
                 Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                 ->  Index Scan using car_list_query_index on cars  (cost=0.56..417930.45 rows=1 width=1235) (actual time=706.665..706.665 rows=0 loops=1)
                       Index Cond: (("publicationDate" >= (now() - '250 days'::interval)) AND (mileage >= '122000'::double precision) AND (mileage <= '182000'::double precision) AND (model = 'qashqai +2'::text) AND (manufacturer = 'nissan'::text) AND ("modelYear" = 2011) AND ("driveWheels" = 'fwd'::drive_wheels) AND ("fuelType" = 'diesel'::fuel_type) AND ("chassisType" = 'mpv'::chassis_type) AND ("registrationClass" = 'passenger'::registration_class) AND ("publisherType" = 'private'::publisher_type) AND (power <= '143'::double precision) AND (power >= '77'::double precision) AND (power <= '500'::double precision) AND ("engineVolume" <= '5'::double precision) AND ("vehicleTransmission" = 'manual'::text))
   CTE full_match
     ->  CTE Scan on min_match min_match_1  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=1 width=616) (never executed)
           Filter: (("engineVolume" = '1.5'::double precision) AND (power = '110'::double precision) AND ("numberOfSeats" = 7))
   ->  Sort  (cost=0.13..0.14 rows=1 width=268) (actual time=706.711..706.711 rows=0 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (CASE WHEN (min_match.state = 'activated'::ad_state) THEN ((('now'::cstring)::date)::timestamp without time zone - min_match."publicationDate") WHEN (min_match."unPublicationDate" IS NULL) THEN (age((('now'::cstring)::date)::timestamp with time zone, (('now'::cstring)::date)::timestamp with time zone) - '1 year'::interval) ELSE ((('now'::cstring)::date)::timestamp without time zone - min_match."unPublicationDate") END), (((abs((min_match.power - '110'::double precision)) + abs((min_match."engineVolume" - '1.5'::double precision))) + (abs((min_match."numberOfSeats" - 7)))::double precision)), (abs((min_match.mileage - '152000'::double precision))), min_match."lastUpdateDate" DESC
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..0.12 rows=1 width=268) (actual time=706.688..706.688 rows=0 loops=1)
               Join Filter: (full_match."id" = min_match."id")
               ->  CTE Scan on min_match  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=240) (actual time=706.686..706.686 rows=0 loops=1)
               ->  CTE Scan on full_match  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (never executed)
 Planning time: 1.777 ms
 Execution time: 706.913 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you have index scans.  It's better than a table scan but a seek would be more ideal.  I would move publicationdate and mileage down on the index list.  You want the exact matches to seek first.

```
CREATE INDEX car_list_query_index
ON car_list_view (
                  "model",
                  "manufacturer",
                  "modelYear",
                  "driveWheels",
                  "fuelType",
                  "chassisType",
                  "registrationClass",
                  "publisherType",
                  "vehicleTransmission",
                 "publicationDate",
                  "mileage",
                  "power",
                  "engineVolume",
                  "numberOfSeats");
```

Comment: Thank you! That did help :) When running it through explain analyze it still uses index scan from what I can see in the explain analyze part, but it's faster :)

Comment: @user16655 PostgreSQL EXPLAIN always calls them scans.  The "Index Cond" field doesn't distinguish between conditions that offer skip-to selectivity, and ones that merely offer in-index filtering capabilities.  I think it is a flaw in EXPLAIN.